# can not read property navigate of undefined

Tags: react-native

I am mapping array to component.

```
{this.state.forms.map((data)=><Box  data={data} />)}
```

and the code for component Box is

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {View,Text,ScrollView,Image,Button,StyleSheet,AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'

class Login extends Component{


    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            forms:[],
        }
        this.onSetCompany = this.onSetCompany.bind(this)
    }
    onSetCompany(data){
            console.log(data)   
//          AsyncStorage.setItem('Company',data);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('CompanyDeatails')

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={style.container}>
                {console.log(this.props.data)}
                <View style={style.box}>
                    <View style={style.box1}>
                        <Text style={style.row2}>{this.props.data.CompanyName} bkb</Text>
                    </View> 
                    <View style={style.box3}>
                        <Text style={style.row2}>{this.props.data.LastDate} </Text>
                    </View>
                        </View>
                <View style={style.buttonBox}>
                    <View style={style.button}>
                        <Button  color="#6d5d17" title="Fill" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('CompanyDeatails')}></Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Login


var style = StyleSheet.create({
 .....  

})
```

and my Routes

```
export default class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
                <Links />
            )
    }
}

const Links = DrawerNavigator({.....,
                            CompanyDeatails:{screen:CompanyDeatails},
                                ....,
                                },{contentComponent:props => <Slider {...props}/>
                            })
```

When i Map array to Box then navigation in that box is not working.I have working navigation to which are working on my rest of app but not in this particular component. 
 
Like
in login.js, I have             `this.props.navigation.navigate('C1')`
Which is working but when I paste same line in Box component it throw error.
**Can not read property navigate of undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Box` component is not part of `navigator` then, you should wrap it within `withNavigation` function inorder to access the `navigation` object. Take a look at the doc [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)

Consider the following example

```
import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Box extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Box);
```

Now, within the Box component, you can access `this.props.navigation.navigate` function.

Hope this will help!

Comment: I just started react-native and I learnt quite valuable concept from this answer . Thankyou for your ans.

Comment: Glad to hear this.